# Change html page and parse websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I work with JS websockets and try to create a login together with a python websocket server. I want that the user sends his passwort and name to the server and get redirect to my `main.html` when the login is correct. The thing is; when I redirect to the main page, my websocket disappears. When I try to parse the websocket with localstorage, the `.send` method of the websocket disappears.

```js
let websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.177:1234/");
websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let type = data.type;
  if (type == "login") {
    window.location.pathname = ""long path"/main.html";
  }
};
```

In my `main.js`, which loads in the `main.html`, I want to get this websocket so that I can send and receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I have changed my Project and do not need a WebSocket anymore I now know that it seems to be not possible. A JS WebSocket will be lost always the connection when you switch the HTML site. But it exists a workaround. You can youse shared workers which hold the WebSocket in the background. I did not test it but with this technique, it should work. Also notes that it seems that shared workers do not exist for Safari. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker.